# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 Error with React, Babel and Webpack

Tags: express, webpack, sequelize.js, babeljs, epilogue

I am building a CRUD web application using Webpack, Express, Epilogue, Sequelize, Sqlite3 and React. After setting up Webpack and Babel, I can add entries to the database but not retrieve entries. When I add an entry, if I look at http://localhost:3000/blogposts (one of my endpoints) the page is blank, but in the server output I see my entries get added.

[server output in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hppGB.jpg)

To retrieve entries from the database I use:

```
 getPosts = async () => {
           const response = await fetch('/blogposts');
           const data = await response.json();
           data.forEach(item => item.editMode = false);
           this.setState({ data })
       }
```

And I get the error: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1

[full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNwH6.png)

I assume this is an error with babel/webpack and await/async.

my webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader",
            options: { minimize: true }
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      },
      {
       test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
       use: ['file-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./src/index.html",
      excludeChunks: [ 'server' ]
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*",".js", ".jsx", "json"],
    alias: {
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '/components')
    }      
},

}
```

my webpackserver.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path')
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    server: './src/server/server.js',
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  target: 'node',

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    alias: {
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '/components')
    }      
},
  node: {
    __dirname: false,   
    __filename: false,  
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()], 
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }

  
}
```

my server.js:

```js
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'

require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const { ExpressOIDC } = require('@okta/oidc-middleware');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const epilogue = require('epilogue'), ForbiddenError = epilogue.Errors.ForbiddenError;
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express(),
            DIST_DIR = __dirname,
            HTML_FILE = path.join(DIST_DIR, '/src/index.html')
app.use(express.static(DIST_DIR))
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(HTML_FILE)
})
// session support is required to use ExpressOIDC
app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.RANDOM_SECRET_WORD,
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

const oidc = new ExpressOIDC({
    issuer: `${process.env.OKTA_ORG_URL}/oauth2/default`,
    client_id: process.env.OKTA_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret: process.env.OKTA_CLIENT_SECRET,
    redirect_uri: process.env.REDIRECT_URL,
    scope: 'openid profile',
    routes: {
        callback: {
            path: '/authorization-code/callback',
            defaultRedirect: '/admin'
        }
    }
});

// ExpressOIDC will attach handlers for the /login and /authorization-code/callback routes
app.use(oidc.router);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'src')));
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './home.html'));
 });
 
 app.get('/admin', oidc.ensureAuthenticated(), (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './admin.html'));
 });

app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/home');
});
console.log("redirect");
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/home');
});

// //for each blog post
app.get('/lifestyle/:title', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Blogpost template here!')
  })

const database = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: './db.sqlite',
    operatorsAliases: false,
});

const Post = database.define('posts', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    content: Sequelize.TEXT,
});

const blogPost = database.define('blogposts', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    content: Sequelize.TEXT,
    published: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
});

const test = database.define('test', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    content: Sequelize.TEXT,
});

epilogue.initialize({ app, sequelize: database });

const PostResource = epilogue.resource({
    model: Post,
    endpoints: ['/posts', '/posts/:id'],
});

const blogPostResource = epilogue.resource({
    model: blogPost,
    endpoints: ['/blogposts', '/blogposts/:id'],
});


PostResource.all.auth(function (req, res, context) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve(context.continue);
    })
});

database.sync().then(() => {
    oidc.on('ready', () => {
        app.listen(port, () => console.log(`My Blog App listening on port ${port}!`))
    });
});

oidc.on('error', err => {
    // An error occurred while setting up OIDC
    console.log("oidc error: ", err);
});
```

my package.json:

```js
   {
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rm -rf dist && webpack --mode development --config webpackserver.config.js && webpack --mode development",
    "start": "node ./dist/server.js"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@okta/oidc-middleware": "1.0.2",
    "D": "1.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "cors": "2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "6.2.0",
    "epilogue": "0.7.1",
    "express": "4.16.4",
    "express-session": "1.15.6",
    "fibers": "4.0.2",
    "node-sass": "4.13.0",
    "rc": "1.2.8",
    "sass": "1.23.7",
    "sequelize": "4.44.3",
    "sqlite3": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-isomorphic-tools": "3.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.7.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.7.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.7.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.7.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.5.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.7.0",
    "css-loader": "3.3.2",
    "file-loader": "5.0.2",
    "grommet": "2.9.0",
    "html-loader": "0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "nodemon": "1.18.9",
    "nodemon-webpack-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "react": "16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.0",
    "style-loader": "1.0.1",
    "styled-components": "4.4.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "0.0.75",
    "webpack": "4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2"
  }
}
```

my .babelrc"

```
{
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/react"
],
"plugins" : [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime" 
]
```

}

Comment: Usually this happens because you have fetched something which you expect to be JSON, but is not. Have you tried simply fetching (with postman or curl, not a browser) /blogposts (taking care to set headers, etc) to see what is returned?

Comment: Thank you! I used curl and realized the /blogposts URL was just my index.html file, instead of JSON.